# Can't register an app with multiple platforms - ios and android - using MFP Console

Tags: android, ios, ibm-mobilefirst, registration

I found a strange behavior when registering an app for both iOS and Android thru MFP Console (without using CLI). Using CLI for the registration works fine for both iOS and Android versions of the same app, but there seems to be no way to register an app (same app) for both iOS and Android using Console, having the following error,

> "FWLSE3051E: Invalid payload. See additional messages for details.
>   FWLSE2319E: Deployable validation failed. The application with the
>   displayName "TestApp" already in use. Please use a different display
>   name."

Is this normal? or is there any other way to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error will occur if using the same **Application Name**, but not the same **Application Identifier**.

Use the **same** Application Name and Application Identifier for your apps, but each with a **different Platform** to logically "combine" applications in the MobileFirst Operations Console.